# How to show/hide checkbox when buttons toggled?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I started Qt Designer to create a window for the Maya tool.
I'm making the same GUI as Snap of Blender. How do I make the display change like this?
What is it called in Qt to show a different one for each button?

[image: In Increment Absolute Grid Snap only]
[image: In Face more menu]
[image: making]

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of

[image: Layouts]

#### 1. Use a [StackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) (left)

A StackedWidget is a container that contains multiple widgets, but shows only one at a time. You can set which one is visible with [`.setCurrentIndex(int index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) and `.setCurrentWidget(QWidget*)`.

This is basically what you want to do, except by default it is going stay **as tall as the tallest widget**, even with a spacer (as visible on the screenshot).

This can be forced manually, or you can even create your own widget to do that (https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28514-How-can-i-achieve-an-auto-resizing-QStackedWidget), but it defeats a bit its ease of use.

#### 2. Widgets, hide/show, spacer (right)

The second option, really basic, is to create different Widgets that will act as containers, and that you will toggle (`.show()`/`.hide`) whenever a button is pressed. This can even be done from the Designer of QtCreator if you are looking for the easiest way to achieve it.

- Make your buttons `checkable`, and `exclusive` (as you probably did)
- Connect to the `clicked(bool checked)` or `toggled(bool checked)` signal
- Call `show`/`hide` on the container widgets to show only one. Et voila!

```
MyWidget:MyWidget(...)
{  
  connect(ui->vertexButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWidget::onButtonClicked);
}

void MyWidget::onButtonClicked(bool checked) {
  button = sender();
  if (button == ui->vertexButton) {
    ui->vertexContent->show();
    ui->edgeContent->hide();
  } else if ...
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried to compile the code above